# Magento checkout system randomly locks up

Tags: magento, checkout

So I've put together a very basic Magento website (I'm quite amateur at web development, you'll notice I'm even using the regular RWD theme that comes with Magento) -- so far everything is working great.

I only have one extension and that is One Page Checkout from IWD Extensions.

This system has been working fine without issue for over a month, now suddenly and without any coding changes it seems to lock up after someone enters their shipping address (almost like it is stuck validating something).

What makes it infuriating is that this issue is completely random. I first noticed it yesterday morning, then it stopped, now it's back again. I have problems reproducing it all the time because of how random it is.

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with it?

The site is http://dev01.offthetruckjewels.com.au and the issue is evident when going to the checkout and entering your details (before you click "Place Order"

Comment: -- Okay, so I disabled the IWD extension and now have noticed that the base/default checkout appears to be shot as well.

everything works, but 'Place Order' is no longer there.

Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I restored to a backup I had for the site before I even loaded the IWD extension and voila! Works like a charm.

Must have installed it improperly.